# How do I connect my dapp to metamask from both web and mobile browser

Tags: javascript, metamask, nft, web3modal

I am working on a nft marketplace and I want to connect metamask from both web and mobile browser, it works very fine in web browser but when it comes to mobile browser it doesn't work at all. I use web3Modal library and I couldn't help to connect from mobile.

here is the code for connecting to the wallet:

```
  const web3Handler = async () => {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const provider = await web3Modal.connect();
    const accounts = await provider.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    setAccount(accounts[0]);
    const ethersProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(provider);
    const signer = ethersProvider.getSigner();

    provider.on("chainChanged", () => {
      window.location.reload();
    });

    provider.on("accountsChanged", async function (accounts) {
      setAccount(accounts[0]);
      await web3Handler();
    });

    loadContracts(signer);
  };
```